# Any idea how to determine the convergence of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I determine the convergence of the following series?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + (-1)^n}}$$

I've tried many techniques, such as trying to split the expression, into two series of even and odd, but without luck. Also tried to simplify, but no luck as well.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: Note that the sum is not defined at $n=1$ !

Comment: @xavierm02 How do you define equivalent?  It's not enough that $u_n/v_n \to 1$, since the terms are not all positive.  The limit comparison test is invalid if used naively like this.

Comment: @xavierm02 Elementary counterexample: $$u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1n.$$

Comment: @OP Let $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n + (-1)^n}}$. Did you try to estimate $u_{2n}+u_{2n+1}$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is it? How? I see much simpler "friends" around...

Comment: @Did I have tried estimating the expressions that you've mentioned.
Got an combination of divergent series.

Comment: @ChenMordechay This is awfully vague. Please describe what you call "combination of divergent series". (IOW, rather than paraphrasing it, please show what you did.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{n=2}^{2N+1}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{\sqrt{2n+1}}-\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}=-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}\left(\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{2n+1}\right)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is interesting to see not only the convergence but the closed form of this series. We have $$\sum_{n=2}^{2N+1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+\left(-1\right)^{n}}}=-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)
 $$ so  taking the limit $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+\left(-1\right)^{n}}}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n^{1/2}}=\eta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\approx-0.395101
 $$ where $\eta\left(s\right)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: 3 downvote without any comment. It is very constructive, and surely it will help people to learn math.